# How to integrate a function with respect to a variable that that function is itself also a function of?

Tags: integration

That title is a mouthful.

Say $\theta$ is a function of t such that $\theta(t)$, and I want to integrate:
$$\int\sin\theta dt$$

In this case I probably can't just treat $\sin\theta$ as a constant and take it out the integral...

Comment: No you cannot treat it as a constant, because it isn't constant. You need an expression for $\theta(t)$. Fundamentally your question is the same as asking, "How do I integrate $\int f(t) dt$?" Well, give me $f(t)$ and I can tell you.

Comment: @innerproduct when you put it like that it makes me laugh at my own question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that there is a function $g$ such that $\theta=g(t)$ for all $t$, we can write your integral as
$$
I=\int \sin\left(g(t)\right) \, dt \, .
$$
The issue is that there is no general formula for the value of this integral. For instance, if $g(t)=e^t$, then I believe that $I$ cannot be expressed in terms of [elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function). However, if the function $\sin \circ g$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, then
$$
I=\int_{0}^{t}\sin(g(x)) \, dx+C
$$
This follows from the [first fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#First_part).

Comment: OK, so it would depend on how g(t) was defined. Ok cool thanks. I did think maybe this was the case but I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something obvious.

Comment: @Tsvanden: I'm glad I could help. Keep in mind that there isn't a 'chain rule' for integration. Although we have the explicit formula $$\frac{d}{dx}\left(f(g(x))\right)=f'(g(x)) \cdot g'(x) \, ,$$there isn't a direct equivalent for integration.

Comment: Ah, yes that's exactly what I was wondering if I'm missing - a chain rule for integration.

Answer (score 0):

As you have noted yourself, you can't treat $\sin(\theta)$ as a constant, since it is not, $\theta(t)$ depends on $t$ in general. One way to make it clear is to just consider $\theta(t) = t$, then your integral becomes

$$\int\sin(t)dt$$

where it obviously makes no sense to move $\sin(t)$ outside of the integral.

I don't think there's a general way to handle such situations all the time (as there is no general 'road map' that covers how to integrate all possible functions...), but often enough you can use a change of variables to deal with it. For example, let's say that $\theta(t) = 2t$, so that you have to integrate

$$\int \sin(2t) dt. $$

This can easily handled with a substitution. (Is this something you are familiar with?)

I hope this helps.

Comment: Ok cool. So basically there's no general way to proceed unless $\theta$ is more explicitly defined. Thanks!